# Why can't I run Matlab executable from Python?

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have a Matlab executable and MCR from someone else. I can run the executable just fine by double clicking and through a batch script. However, when I try to run the executable within Python I get an error telling me it can't find the MCR. Here are the calls I have tried:

```
os.system('application.exe')
subprocess.Popen(['application.exe'])
subprocess.call(['application.exe'])
```

As requested, here is the complete error message, it comes from application.exe and not from Python.

> Could not find version 7.15 of the MCR.
>       Attempting to load mclmcrrt7_15.dll.
>       Please install the correct version of the MCR.
>       Contact your vendor if you do not have an installer for the MCR.

I guess I should also mention I am using Python 3.5 and application.exe was compiled with R2011a. I am using PyCharm for my Python development.

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated! This is also a bit time sensitive, so the sooner the better :)

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path?

Comment: @user5797292: Please put the complete error message into your question.

Comment: @NineBerry: The path is probably right, otherwise it would not start searching for the Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR). Searching for the runtime is done by the executable created with the Matlab Compiler.

Comment: @user5797292: Try to start application.exe from the same command prompt from which you start python. Does application.exe start?

Comment: @durasm Yes, I can run application.exe from the command line and via a batch file.

Comment: MCR is searched using the "path" environment variable. I don't know how python behaves when creating a process, but I assume it is lost for some reason.

Comment: @user5797292: Print out env. PATH variable from PYTHON script and check if MCR is there.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I was able to solve the problem with your help. It appears that Python was not correctly interpreting my environment variables and I needed to add the MCR to the
    os.environ(['PATH'])